# Issue with changing Apple ID

Tags: apple-id

My email address no longer active and valid and I need to change it.

Once I log in and access the "Change Apple ID" page and enter a valid email address, I get an error message "This email address is not available. Choose a different address."

Comment: log in with what credentials

Answer (score 2):

Most likely the problem is is that that email is used as a recovery email for another Apple ID.

According to [this Apple Support discussion:](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6427949)

> The issue was that I wanted to create an account with an address that
>   was already listed as a secondary address for an another, older, Apple
>   ID account.
>
> This situation blocks the Apple ID creation process (and because the
>   email is not a primary address for any Apple ID yet, there is no
>   birthdate associated with it and the recovery emails go nowhere)
>
> To solve the problem I went to id.apple.com, clicked "manage your ID"
>   and logged in with my old account credentials.
>
> I then deleted the email address that I wanted to use to create an ID
>   from the list of "alternate emails" associated with the old account
>   and victory! After that the Apple ID creation process went fine.

Comment: iirc, you can add it back later as a recovery address; but this one stumped me for years, as someone who has managed to collect over the years a mac.com address, a personal domain address for when iTunes was started, then a me.com & lastly an icloud.com... which is at least correctly tied to the me.com... 15 years of ID juggling & still we cannot merge IDs... :\